# Auth0 loginWithRedirect Adding Code and State Parameters to URL Causing isAuthenticated to Return False

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, single-page-application, auth0

When I use the `loginWithRedirect` function from the `useAuth`0 hook the redirect adds the `code` and `state` parameters to the URL. However, when these parameters are added to the URL the `isAuthenticated` flag from the useAuth0 hook returns `false`. When I remove the parameters the `isAuthenticated` flag from the `useAuth0` hook returns `true` (as intended). I don't understand why this is happening or how to avoid this issue. Is there a reason Auth0 is adding these parameters onto the URL after redirect?